# Automatic resizing of the Windows Forms controls

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I'm using VS2008's designer for doing this.

For example if I've a windows form of size say 500x500 and I added a DataGridView to it (490x490).

when I run this program. and maximize the form, the DataGridView still remains of the same size. rest of the additional space is blank on the form. I want DataGridView to also take the entire window size.

No software will be like that. I don't know what to change inorder get desired behaviour.

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use Dock, or for more precise control use the Anchor property.  By setting Anchor to Left, Right, Top, Bottom the control will scale with the window.  By setting Anchor to Right the control will move with the right border.  By setting Anchor to Top and Bottom the control will scale vertically, but have a fixed width.  Just experiment

Comment: And when I want to resize the controls to particular value. e.g. Control.Size *= 2 on resizing the form?

Answer (score 19):

You can ether set the `Dock`-Property of your DataGridView instance to `DockStyle.Fill` or use the `Anchor`-Property and set the anchors to:

```
dataGridView.Anchor = 
    AnchorStyles.Bottom | 
    AnchorStyles.Right | 
    AnchorStyles.Top | 
    AnchorStyles.Left;
```

The first method will make your DataGridView to fill your whole client area. The second method will keep the ratio and only resize the control if the container resizes.

Answer (score 8):

for filled up docking inside the winform use:

```
dataGridView.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
```

Answer (score 6):

Set the *Dock* property of the *DataGridView* to Fill.

Answer (score 2):

If you need other things like textbox , picturebox etc as auto scaling then go to their relevant anchor property and set is according to your desire result.