# How do I automatically move and resize buttons and labels when a form is expanded?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2015

So I am using a form application that has buttons and labels in it ([Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FOFqi.jpg)) and I want to know how to make them re-size properly when I maximize the form. The anchor or/and dock property as in these questions: [C# form auto resize window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8001797/c-sharp-form-auto-resize-window) or [Automatic resizing of the Windows Forms controls](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1636280/automatic-resizing-of-the-windows-forms-controls) does not help because it expands only 1 item.

I need it to move and resize without going out of the original proportions. So like let's say I have 2 buttons above each other. I want them to stay always on the right side and they are each 10*12 pixels and 2 pixels from edge. When I expand the original window size three times, each button will still be 2 pixels from the edge but 30*36 pixels big.

Comment: write your own code in `OnResize` event

Comment: I know about OnResize but I dont know how to make it fully dynamic

Comment: Well, I suggest you keep the original layout info and calculate from scratch each time. You will also use the anchoring info to decide what to calculate. You can try to save the original sizes in the controls' tag property..

Answer (score 3):

You need the anchor property set on each control on the form. Note that if you anchor two opposite sides, the control will be stretched/squashed, but if you only anchor to one side, the control will instead *move*.

Note that it's not normal behaviour for a Winforms app to have all controls on a form resize proportionally - you choose the controls that need to stretch (panels, treeviews, images, listboxes etc), and then the standard controls (inputs, buttons, dropdowns etc) should keep the same size but move around (i.e. anchor to top and/or right).

If you're trying to do some sort of "kiosk mode" for your app, then you'd typically run at a lower resolution and/or higher DPI to get the proportional resizing effect, which wouldn't require changes to your app as long as you've applied the idiomatic style of anchoring in your forms.

Comment: Yes it does. If you anchor to left and right, it will resize by stretching horizontally. If you anchor to top and bottom, it will resize by stretching vertically. You can anchor to any combination of top, bottom, left and right to get what you want. I might not understand your requirements if this doesn't work for you, as in all my many years working with WinForms, anchoring has always been good enough for my needs.

Answer (score 1):

This is an example code for 12 buttons (4x3). It also changes the font size compared to the button size.

1. Open a windows form
2. Create 12 buttons
3. Use the code below:

   public Form1()
       {
           InitializeComponent();
           SetComponents();
       }

   ```
   void SetComponents()
   {
       foreach (Control item in Controls)
       {
           if (item is Button)
           {
               item.Width = Size.Width / 4 - 16;
               item.Height = Size.Height / 4;
               item.Font = new Font(Font.FontFamily, item.Height / 5);
           }

           button1.Left = 10;
           button1.Top = 10;

           button2.Left = button1.Right + 10;
           button2.Top = button1.Top;

           button3.Left = button2.Right + 10;
           button3.Top = button2.Top;

           button4.Left = button3.Right + 10;
           button4.Top = button3.Top;

           button5.Left = button1.Left;
           button5.Top = button1.Bottom + 10;

           button6.Left = button5.Right + 10;
           button6.Top = button2.Bottom + 10;

           button7.Left = button6.Right + 10;
           button7.Top = button3.Bottom + 10;

           button8.Left = button7.Right + 10;
           button8.Top = button4.Bottom + 10;

           button9.Left = button1.Left;
           button9.Top = button5.Bottom + 10;

           button10.Left = button9.Right + 10;
           button10.Top = button6.Bottom + 10;

           button11.Left = button10.Right + 10;
           button11.Top = button7.Bottom + 10;

           button12.Left = button11.Right + 10;
           button12.Top = button8.Bottom + 10;

       }
   }

   private void Form1_Resize(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       SetComponents();
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You could put your buttons, etc in a `tableLayoutPanel` with one column and multiple rows(the number of element you want to place). Set the anchor of the tableLayout to "top" and "bottom". Then put one button/label in each row.

Define each row size with a percentage value:

```
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[i].SizeType = SizeType.Percent;
tableLayoutPanel1.RowStyles[i].Height = 20.0F; //=20%
```

Finally set the anchor of each element to "top" and "bottom" too.